# Disabling SSLv3 due to Poodle bug causes to issue with Facebook and open graph

Tags: facebook, curl, nginx, sslv3

I use Nginx and added the line: ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; to my server directive.
It disabled SSLv3 with success but causes to another issue with Facebook.

Facebook doesn't manage to read open graph tags and I get the error:

```
Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

Anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: Facebook reacted to this bug quite quickly, at least when it comes to their API. If they did not update their own scraping tool the same way, then I’d suggest you file a bug report.

Comment: It's not only the scarping tool, the posts are not shown properly on FB when I disable SSLv3.